# How to use expo module in react-native app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have existing react-native project and I want to use [expo-in-app-purchases](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-in-app-purchases) module, and can't find clear doc how to do that. **unimodules** from its README are deprecated, and not sure that [migration](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/expo-modules-migration.md) is the right one.

I want only one module, without migrating to expo.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use 'expo-in-app-purchases' you have to install *Expo modules*, as stated in docs:

> You must ensure that you have installed and configured Expo modules before     continuing.

It doesn't mean that you have to migrate the whole project to expo. There are two scenarios:

1. You don't have *Expo modules* in your project: use [automatic installation](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/#automatic-installation),
2. You have `react-native-unimodules` installed: migrate to *Expo modules* using this [guide](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/expo-modules-migration.md)